# make a php file write into mysql before processing the uploaded file

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, file, upload

As of now I have first code that inserts into a table, then

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$key], $tp)) {   }
```

I am trying to read the inserted record outside the actual file upload handler as the upload is in progress with javascript. It seems that the record gets inserted only after the file has been uploaded.

How to prevent this by allowing a write to mysql and then initiate the upload progress.

Useful for uploading large files, I am trying to let the person set information about the uploaded file as the file is uploading, have developed a beautiful progress bar with php 5.4 using upload_progress_key and so, but the problem is I can't get to know if the file information is on the database to allow for editing custom parameters set by the user.

Thanks for the first down vote here, appreciate it.

THIS IS WHAT I DO:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES VALUES");
```

GREAT so far,

NOW

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $dest);
```

The problem is while trying to read as a 700mb file is being uploaded at file_upload.php

read.php contents:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE values="values");
```

RETURNS 0

up until the uploaded has fully finished and now it returns 1.

So what does it have to do with move_uploaded_file()

and mysql_query("INSERT INTO");

that although on the syntax is first written mysql_query("INSERT INTO");

it appears that this is not happening up until the file gets fully uploaded to the server.

Comment: More context please. File uploads have nothing to do with MySQL as such, it depends on how you're tying them together. It's hard to understand what you're doing and why you can't do it in reverse.

Comment: If I get your problem right, I think you misunderstand the HTTP principle here. The POST Request with the 700 MB file included is first processed completely before PHP even kicks in. So you can't process anything before the upload is complete.

Comment: anyway, I could set $_SESSION['val']='val'; and read although a file was being uploaded, but with smaller sizes, so I don't know what is the difference now.

Comment: so you are using an ajax script to display the progress of the upload? I don't really get the problem from your description.

Comment: It appears asides from reading the upload progress nothing else can't be done until the file is completely uploaded. I wanted to retrieve the id of the file in the database as the file was being uploaded, as this id was being generated on file_upload.php but now I'd just create the id outside sort to say... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File uploads in PHP work like this:

- user selects file to upload in browser, submits the form
- the browser uploads the form, including file, to the *web server*
- the web server writes the received file to a temporary location
- when the entire upload is finished, the web server initiates the PHP script

In other words, by the time the PHP script is run, the upload is already long finished. `move_uploaded_file` just moves the file on the server's hard disk, it does not initiate the actual upload, as you seem to assume.

If you want to do anything before the file upload, you'll have to make an AJAX request to another PHP script or otherwise communicate outside the request cycle in which the file is being uploaded.